# Qt Drawing along with Multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have developed a drawing application using Qt in C++. Now, whenever user draw a stroke and release the mouse button, I am calling an update function with the current drawn image passed as input. Now, till the update function is complete, I cannot draw another stroke. I know it can be solved with multi threading but I am new to it and I don't have much idea how to use it.

```
void ScribbleArea::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton && scribbling) {
        drawLineTo(event->pos());
        lastCursor = event->pos();
        QImage visibleImage = image;
        resizeImage(&visibleImage, size());
        visibleImage.save("temp", "jpg");
        Mat testImg=imread("temp");
        updateShadow(testImg);
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is unclear. Your issues seem to come from the fact that you save and load jpeg images at each mouserelease event

Comment: @UmNyobe Are you saying that if I had used some converter instead of saving and loading images, then I can draw continuously even if updateShadow function hadn't finished ?